# Scala Semantic Equality

Tags: scala

I have this code:

```scala
case class BooleanArr( a1: Array[Boolean] )

val ba1 = BooleanArr(Array(true,false))
val ba2 = BooleanArr(Array(true,false))
println(ba1 == ba2)
```

This prints false, of course.  How can I test equality so that it is true?  I mean--I know that these are two different instances in memory so they're not "equal" (the same), but I want a way to see that they're "equal" (having same values).  Is that possible without a field-by-field hand-coded check?

(Oddly... I learned this works as I'd wish if I use List instead of Arrays... but my use case requires Array, unfortunately.)

Comment: See linked answer about using `sameElements` to compare `Array` for equality.

Comment: I guess he is looking for class equality not array, an array is just a part of that case class so the concept is important

Comment: Why do you need **Arrays** instead of **Lists** or **ArraySeqs** or any other real collection?